# Asynchronously Reading From SSH Output

Tags: asynchronous, ssh, go, io

I'd like to write a function that takes a SSH session and runs a command, providing an `io.Reader` that reads its output as it is recieved.

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "io"
)

func StreamOutput(session *ssh.Session, command string) (output io.Reader, err error) {
    if session != nil {
        defer session.Close()
    }
    if err != nil {
        return output, err
    }
    // connect to both outputs
    outReader, err := session.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return output, err
    }
    errReader, err := session.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return output, err
    }
    output = io.MultiReader(outReader, errReader)
    err = session.Start(command)
    // return the readers that are to be read from
    return output, err
```

When I test this code using an `ioutil.ReadAll` on `output`, however, it only prints the appropriate output intermittently, even after calling `session.Wait()`. Why might this be? Is there a better way to return the functions output (channels, perhaps?)? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean that it only prints the appropriate output intermittently? Is there an error returned by ReadAll? (This code also can't compile, are you using something different?)

Comment: The above code fixed the error. I am using something different, but I am certain that the changes aren't substrantial to the question I have. I mean that sometimes when it is run it prints the output of the command, and other times prints nothing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had the following code in my function:

```
if session != nil {
    defer session.Close()
}
```

That way, the output would only print if the command completed and sent back its stdout before the function returned (which was infrequent). I fixed my code simply by removing these lines.